# Show/hide divs on page load and by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's button groups to toggle between different content. An example can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/g8KSf/

Basically, if you click "Games", the games_container div will appear and the other divs will be hidden. I've got that working fine.

I store the post type in the database as post, game, video, etc and I want to be able to open the related div on page load instead of just on click. Right now the post_container is shown by default when the page is loaded.

Say I have a PHP variable `$post_type = 'game';`, how can I make the game_container show on page load while still having it toggle by clicking?

This is the js I have so far:

```
$('.container').hide();
$('#post_container').show();

$('.post_types button').click(function(){
        var target = "#" + $(this).data("target");
        $(".container").not(target).hide();
        $(target).show();
        $('#post_type').val($(this).text());
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show game container on load, you need to replace this line

```
$('#post_container').show();
```

to

```
$('#game_container').show();
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/g8KSf/4/)**

And also currently you are using

```
$('#post_type').val($(this).text());
```

Here rather than using `this` for this line `$(this).text()`, use `target` variable as below

```
$('#post_type').val($(target).text());
```

### UPDATE:

To show dynamically on page load,

1. Store the value of post_type in variable

   `var ptype = ...STORE THE POST TYPE VALUE...;`
2. Pass the value to this line

   `$('#'+ptype+'_container').show();`
   **OR**
   `$('#'+$post_type+'_container').show();`

Refer **[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/g8KSf/6/)**

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear, I want it to be dynamic. If the post_type is 'video', it should automatically show that div on page load.

Answer (score 0):

change `$('#post_container').show();` to `$('#game_container').show();`

here you go http://jsfiddle.net/g8KSf/5/

I am not so familiar with `php`, for dynamic here:

```
function(){ $.ajax({ 
       type:"GET", 
       url:"file.php", 
       data:id, 
       success:function(container){ 
           $('#'+container).show();
       }, 
       // ... more ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `show()` on page load using the selector you like.

```
$(function() {
    $('#<?=$post_type?>_container').show();
});
```

`<?=?>` short PHP for echo, you can not use that in you .js file. If the way I pointed out is not ok for you, you should set a global variable to the selector you like and use that instead of the inline PHP.

Comment: Please refrain from using php short tags, unless it's PHP 5.4+ (for echos), as stated in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/200666/1478467)

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- change the second line's `#post_container` to `#game_container` directly in your JavaScript code
- or call `$('#btn-game').click();` afterwards, e.g. in the `onload` attribute of the `body` or in a separated `script` tag.